# Python - Pass Arguments to setup file

Tags: python, arguments, version, py2exe, setup.py

I have a setup file that creates an executable using py2exe. To run the setup file I enter

`python setup.py py2exe`.

I would like to pass versioning information so that the executable generated will be created in a specialized directory with the version, as well as set up versioning metadata.

I tried using argparse but that seems to override the setup.py parameters.

Is there a way to pass additional parameters to setup.py elegantly; preferably with flags? `python setup.pu py2exe -v [VERSION]`

I know I can parse the command in python but I would like to be able to specify flags if possible...

Comment: Why not use a simple version file and load it to the setup.py ?

Comment: My architecture uses Makefiles to build everything, therefore the Makefile would run the setup.py and pass the version #. I would prefer to not have to create additional documents that the application relies on.

Comment: Ok I tend to do the opposite a version.txt file that I load in my makefile and setup.py, anyway why not  use environment variable then ?